# Sniff out the actual request that has activated a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm facing a problem in my work that has troubled the services for a couple weeks.
I have written a trigger to try to catch the origin or a bug. but it's like searching a needle in a haystack.

Is there any way to include the DML transaction in a var so that i can see the actual transaction that is activating the trigger ?

Like imagine :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYSADM.WOW_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE
ON SYSADM.TABLE1 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
NEW.COLUMN1 is null and new.COLUMN2 is not null and NEW.COLUMN in ('A','B')
      )
DECLARE
[...]
V_catch clob;

begin 

[...]
end;
```

===> how do i register inside the V_catch this transaction:
`update table1 set column2 = "WHATEVER" where COLUMN15555 = 1`
that happened following a customer's click in the software ?

i tried by doing some nasty jobs on it by writting custom if condition on every columns to try to get the changed values :

```
if :NEW.column1 is not null then 
v_catch := v_catch || :NEW.column1;
end if;
if :NEW.column2 is not null then 
v_catch := v_catch || :NEW.column2;
end if;
```

[...]

That literally does not work as intended often times as we got notified of the bug, and in the report, v_catch was returning non valuables values, and the bug could still not be located.

I'm pretty sure there could be a method out there to do that, but i'm still a beginners and self learning in PLSQL and SQL for oracle.
Maybe i overlooked something, maybe this is the only method existing.
can any veteran help me out on this pls?

Comment: Did you try to enable **auditing** and see what info Oracle collected for you?

Comment: i did not, i searched after seeing your comment, seems like auditing is not activated. I'll try to drop a mail toward my manager to see if he can reach out the the admin for him to activate it. no idea if he will accept to do it tho.

Comment: i received the answer, i can't have it activated due to various reason, licenses capacities, security protocol and other things i'm not supposed to know.

Comment: That's bad news, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auditing is definitely the right answer. But given that you have a constraint against using auditing, triggers are your next best option.

The trouble is, outside of DDL/system-event triggers or fine-grain auditing (which can use `original_sql_txt` and `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL')`, respectively), I don't think it's possible to get the triggering SQL in a DML trigger in a clean manner. While you'd think you could query `v$session.sql_id`, the query to do so will replace it with itself. However, here's a hack that'll get close, by looking at what cursors are open by the session and were active in the past second.

```
create table tmp55 (col1 integer);

create or replace trigger tr_tmp55 after insert or update or delete on tmp55 for each row
begin
  FOR rec_cursor IN (SELECT oc.*,s.sql_fulltext
                       FROM v$open_cursor oc,
                            v$sql s
                      WHERE oc.sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')
                        AND oc.child_address = s.child_address
                        AND oc.sql_id = s.sql_id
                        AND s.last_active_time >= SYSDATE - 1/86400
                        AND UPPER(sql_fulltext) LIKE '%TMP55%'
                        AND UPPER(sql_fulltext) NOT LIKE '%OPEN_CURSOR%')
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(SUBSTR(rec_cursor.sql_fulltext,1,32676));
  END LOOP; 
end;
```

It could return more than one row, only one of which is the correct SQL. Also to weed down results an assumption is made that the DML will name the table (rather than through a view or synonym). You'll want to change the `dbms_output` to insert into a log table along with helpful identifying session info. Obviously this is rough and can be tweaked, but it gives the basic idea.

Comment: thanks for your insight. and having thought about it yesterday, i kinda made something similar with v_$session and v_$sqlarea. 
in V_$SESSION i can get the address corresponding to the user i'm getting thanks to 

```declare v_session varchar2(20) v_request clob; 
v_list_request clob; 
Cursor cur is 
select * from sys.v_$session x where OSUSER = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER'); begin 
for curs in cur 
loop 
select sql_fulltext into v_requete from SYS.v_$sqlarea where address = curs.sql_address;  v_list_request :=v_list_request||' '|| v_request; 
end loop; 
end;```

Comment: i'm sorry i'm trying to add the code i tried by myself but it's showing up weirdly in comment section. maybe i'm using ' code ' wrongly.

Comment: That won't work. The sql_address, like sql_id, seen in v$session will be the "select * from sys.v_$session" query, not the triggering query.

Comment: I explained in this in my answer and this is why I opted for v$open_cursor instead.

Comment: yes i got that, thanks very much for the work around, i'm gonna try to add the parts into my trigger and test it. 
just wanted to share my thought process about what i did try while asking questions and waiting for helps :)

Comment: Would `v$session.prev_sql_id` capture the triggering SQL ID? (I'm too lazy to set up a test to check this myself.) Also, `utl_call_stack` can tell you the calling PL/SQL object, if there is one, which might get you closer to finding your bug.

Comment: No, prev_sql_id will show you the sql_id prior to the triggering one. I've tested this repeatedly and no matter how I set it up, it never points to the triggering SQL. Yes, you can certainly use the call stack to find a PL/SQL origin, but that's only if stored procs are being used. Otherwise it's just going to say anonymous.